# replace with backspace empty string

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file with [bs] characters. [bs] mean backspace. so I want to replace [bs] with backspace.

```
Ex1: 
source text: 123[bs]45
result must be :1245

Ex2: 
source text: ABC DEF[bs][bs] GHI JKL[bs]
result must be : ABC D GHI JK
```

Comment: A simple loop could do it. No?

Comment: @dotNET can you explain the code plz

Comment: When you say "[bs]," do you mean literally "[bs]" or are you referring to the actual backspace character, '\b'?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I mean [bs]

Comment: @JumRemdesk : I edited my answer so it works with "[bs]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for "[bs]" specification:

```
Public Function ReplaceBackslashWithBackspace(ByVal inputText As String) As String
    Dim replacementChar As Char = "#" ' ... or any character you are 100% you are not using in inputText
    inputText = inputText.Replace("[bs]", replacementChar)
    Dim outputStringBuilder As New Text.StringBuilder
    For charIndex As Integer = 0 To inputText.Length - 1
        If inputText(charIndex) = replacementChar Then
            If outputStringBuilder.Length = 0 Then Continue For
            outputStringBuilder.Length = outputStringBuilder.Length - 1
        Else
            outputStringBuilder.Append(inputText(charIndex))
        End If
    Next
    Return outputStringBuilder.ToString
End Function
```

Test:

```
    Dim result As String = ReplaceBackslashWithBackspace("ABC DEF[bs][bs] GHI JKL[bs]")
    ' result = "ABC D GHI JK"
```

Comment: He said Backspace, not backslash.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Edited. Although I am not 100% sure about the `inputText(charIndex) = ControlChars.Back`, maybe you can confirm or edit the answer.

Comment: You should place a check on the `If` body. `x.Length = x.Length - 1` may throw an exception.

Comment: This does not solve the OP question.  He's not looking for the `ControlChars.Back` character, he's looking for `"[bs]"`.

Comment: ...and edited again for the last time. Thanks @Grim. The "replace" part, although not 100% necessary, makes the code much simpler.

Comment: Even though it took a lot of rework, I still think this is the best answer - much cleaner than the others!

Comment: Thank you very much @Grim. I really appreciate it, specially after all the rework...

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 Dim str, str1 As String
 str1 = ""
 str = "ABC DEF[bs][bs] GHI JKL[bs]"
 While InStr(str, "[bs]") <> 0
 str1 = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("[bs]") + 4)
 str = fun(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("[bs]")))
 str = str & str1
 End While
 MsgBox(str)' will give the output
 End Sub
 Public Function fun(ByVal str As String) As String
 Return (str.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1))
 End Function
```

Comment: Look closely at the question. This is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: This does not remove the previous character, as pressing 'backspace' would.

Comment: sorry for the delay, check the updation

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
  Private Sub BSReplace(ByVal xst As String)

      xstr = xstr.Replace(xstr.Substring(xstr.IndexOf("[") - 1, 5), String.Empty)

      If xstr.Contains("[") Then Call BSReplace(xstr) Else MsgBox(xstr)


 End Sub

 call  Call BSReplace("123[bs]45")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Function ReplaceBS(s As String) As String
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(s.Length)

    For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
        If Convert.ToByte(s(i)) = 8 Then
            If sb.Length > 0 Then sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1)
        Else
            sb.Append(s(i))
        End If
    Next

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: `ReplaceBS` ... I think you did it on purpose. And I like it.

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work because it's not backspace char. it's [bs]. (there is 4 chars)

Comment: @JumRemdesk: You should have typed [bs] as "[bs]" and explicitly call it 'the string "[bs]"'. Merely typing it as [bs] would confuse most experienced users because brackets [] are used to denote placeholders and special characters.